# Fetch all rows that join via a list of values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, rails-activerecord

I have two tables(models):

1. Students
2. Courses

They are both connected via a table called `course_enrollments`

In rails they are set up like so:

```
Student.rb:
has_many :courses, through: course_enrollments

Course.rb:
has_many :students, through: course_entrollments

CourseEntrollment.rb:
belongs_to :student, foreign_key...
belongs_to :course, foreign_key..
```

I would like to fetch **all** Students who are enrolled to **all** courses from a specific list of Courses, something like this:

```
courses_list = current_professor.courses_teaching
student_list = Student.eager_load(:some_table_I_have_to_load).join_with_all_courses(courses_list).order(sort_attributes).paginate....
```

My question is how do I go about doing it? I'm not too strong in SQL and am breaking my head trying to figure out what I need.
I figured I need to put some kind of join, or where clause before the `order` but I'm having some difficulty figuring out what and how to do it properly

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `courses_list` is a relation. it's quite simple to do it:

```
student_list = Student.joins(:course_enrollments).where(course_enrollments: { course_id: courses_list.ids })
```

Comment: Cool, yeah that looks to be what I'm missing. Thanks a lot!